# Changing the User UID of a User with No Name

Tags: ubuntu, users, docker, uid

If a user has an UID but no name, ie:

```
$ whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1001
$ id
uid=1001 gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

is it possible to change the UID but still leave the user name undefined?

---

System info:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.15.0-88-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-036) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)) #88~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 12 04:19:15 UTC 2020
```

Comment: The UID is a unique identifier for a user. To 'change' the UID of a user actually means to point a user database entry to a different UID. When you say that the user name isn't defined, you actually mean that the UID doesn't have an associated user database entry pointing to the UID.

Comment: @Torin Can we manually add the entry in to this database? If so, how can we do it?

Comment: Sure, you can create a user with `adduser --uid 1001 username`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to manually change both the user id and the user name (along with other user attributes) by using [vipw](https://linux.die.net/man/8/vipw). This opens an editor on the password file.

After running `vipw` you should run `vipw -s` and make equivalent changes to the shadow file.

The equivalent utility for editing groups is [vigr](https://linux.die.net/man/8/vigr).

If the user you are changing owns any files, you would likely then need to use `chown` to change ownership to the new user id. (You can use the username in the `chown` call, but the ownership is decided based on user id, not user name.)